# How can I force all implementations to call a specific method in their constructor

Tags: c#, oop

Is it possible to instruct a construct in C# to forcefully call an implementing method?
I've created an interface that forces implementing classes to implement a method. Now I want this method to be called by all constructors of implementing classes.

I know I can create a base class and call the method in its constructor, but I cannot force every child class to call the base class constructor?

Comment: Some code will make it clear.

Comment: You want every default empty constructor of class implementing some interface to call your method? I doubt it is possible. Only idea that comes to my mind is to implement a base class all your classes would derieve from but you still would have 'implement' constructors with ": base()" clause. So it basically doesn't change anything...

Comment: It sounds like the interface has a design smell: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling

Comment: @MarkSeemann , I am agree with you, there must be some provision to enforce constructor to call a method. To force a method to implement , designing two level of base (abstract and interface) classes doesn't sounds good.

Comment: @ImranRizvi Why must there be a provision to force a constructor to call a method?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I want to create an instance of child class , the implemented method should be private and initialize few fields in the child class that is accessed using child instance.

Comment: @ImranRizvi I was more discussing why you believe there *should* be a way to enforce that. Your previous answer is just what you want to do. About the only way you can do that is by baking it into the constructor of the base class, which any derived class will have to call. Everything else won't be enforced, it will be just how you code it. Such as using a factory or something.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I want to be ensure that when I create a child class object it must be filled with the values using the overloaded method and I don't want to repeatedly call all child methods to fill the values.

Comment: @ImranRizvi Then something like making child construction internal and instead constructing children via a factory pattern will allow you to specify that once. That way you stop people constructing child objects without going through the factory pattern you use. Unfortunately, you cannot stop people deriving new child types.

Answer (score 4):

No, Abstract class will be your workaround.

```
public abstract class MyAbstract : IMyInterface
{
    public MyAbstract()
    {
        MyMustCallmethod();
    }
    public abstract void MyInterfaceMember();//Let derived classes implement your interface

    private void MyMustCallmethod()
    {
     //implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call the constructor to an inheriting class (say B inheriting from A), the constructor for the inherited class will be also called. So if you want to make sure that all classes inheriting from A call the Foo method you can set the call in the A constructor:

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        Foo();
    }

    public void Foo() {/* something here */}
}

public class B: A {
    public B(string param) {/* A constructor will be called */}
}
```

poke comment below explains that the default constructor is selected. If no default constructor exists you must call a constructor explicitly.

But you cannot force an interface method to be called because interfaces **contain no implementation**. Using the above code will mean that only the A class will implement the interface. So in order to ensure that inheriting classes call the method and must define  it explicitly i use something like this:

```
public interface IHasFooThatMustBeCalledInConstructor {
    void Foo();
}

public abstract class A: IHasFooThatMustBeCalledInConstructor {
    public A() {
        Foo();
    }

    public abstract void Foo();
}

public class B: A {
    public B(string param) {}
    public void Foo() { };
}
```

Comment: Also, from MSDN: *“In a derived class, if a base-class constructor is not called explicitly by using the base keyword, the default constructor, if there is one, is called implicitly.”* ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx))

Comment: Why would you add another method `FooImpl` and make that abstract, instead of just making the interface member `Foo` abstract? Also, in `B`, it should be `public override void FooImpl() {…}`

Comment: @poke i don't know. i guess i made an assumption about OP's level and didn't want to abstract everything in order to fall from the interface to the base implementation and then to the derived class. I edited the `FooImpl` out